# Brauer equivalence classes over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, division-algebras

How to show that there are infinitely many Brauer equivalence classes over $\mathbb{Q}$? I proved that every such class has exactly one division algebra in it, so the question reduces to showing that there are infinitely many central division algebras over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: What do you know about completion? The way I would prove this result is to show that it is already true over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ where the structure of the Brauer group is more concrete.

Comment: @hunter Well, I have two stupid questions: How then it can be shown that it is true for p-adic field? And how this formally implies the fact that it is true for $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Not stupid questions, the answer to both takes some work but is well-known. 1. For $p$-adic fields the Brauer group is well-known to be $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ and there is an explicit construction (see Milne's notes on class field theory). 2. Tensoring a c.s.a. over $\mathbb{Q}$ with $\mathbb{Q}_p$ gives a surjection from the Brauer group of $\mathbb{Q}$ to the Brauer group of $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: If this is an exercise for a class, it must be the case that the professor had an elementary solution in mind. I will think for a bit. If it's just something you read and you want to know why it is true, probably the thing to do is read this article, especially the section on class field theory: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brauer_group

Comment: What do you know about quaternion algebras? You can explicitly construct infinitely many non-equivalent quaternion algebras, although proving they are non-equivalent is going to take some work

Comment: @hunter, Well, I was suggested by someone to extend $\mathbb{Q}$ with something like $\sqrt{p}, i,j,k$ ($p$ is prime), but such things seem to be non-central.

Comment: try instead letting $i$ be a square root of $-p$ and letting $j$ be a square root of $-1$ (and $ij = -ji =: k$ as usual). Then let $p$ vary.

Comment: @hunter, but are those $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-p},i,j,k]$ central?

Comment: The center of such an algebra is $\mathbb{Q}$. I don't like your notation; there is no element $\sqrt{-p}$ in the algebra. It is $\mathbb{Q}[i, j, k]$ where $i, j$ and $k$ satisfy the relations described above.

Comment: @hunter Thank you, it seems to work. Now I am going to prove that they a really not isomorphic.

Comment: Please do add a write up of your solution as an answer, so that this is no left unanswered.